# ListView with custom adapter. Saving data

Tags: android, listview, ondestroy

**Hello! Simple shopping list app** (ListView with custom rows, custom adapter). Just dealed with famous listview checkbox scroll problem.

Please check my code (for proper viewHolder implementation) and help me find the easiest way to save the data. ( After onDestroy() )

ADAPTER:

```
public class ShopAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mainContex;
private ArrayList<ShopItem> shopItems;

static class ViewHolder {
    CheckBox checkBox;
    TextView textView;
}

public ShopAdapter(Context mainContex, ArrayList<ShopItem> shopItems) {
    this.mainContex = mainContex;
    this.shopItems = shopItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return shopItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return shopItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ShopItem shopItem = shopItems.get(position);
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mainContex);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.shoplist_item, null);

        viewHolder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemTextView);
        viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.doneCheckBox);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.checkBox.setTag(shopItems.get(position));
    viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                shopItem.setDone(true);
                viewHolder.textView.setTextColor(mainContex.getResources()
                        .getColor(R.color.done_text_color));
            } else {
                shopItem.setDone(false);
                viewHolder.textView.setTextColor(mainContex.getResources()
                        .getColor(R.color.secondary_text));
            }
        }
    });
    viewHolder.textView.setText(shopItem.getDescription());
    viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(shopItem.isDone());
    return convertView;
}
```

}

ITEM:

```
public class ShopItem {

private String description;
private boolean done;

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public boolean isDone() {
    return done;
}

public void setDone(boolean done) {
    this.done = done;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you are gonna save data into a listview you should use database, SQLIte is recommended. Please check the link below for a simple tutorial + source code on how to do it!

http://androidtuts4u.blogspot.com.br/2013/02/android-list-view-using-custom-adapter.html